# Values on x-axis in xyplot() in R

Tags: r, lattice

In `R` I want to plot the values from vector `b` against vector `a` (both of length 8) using `xyplot`.
Is it possible to have on the x-axis the range from 0 to 10 such that both vectors can be plot againt each other? Now the x-axis is going from 1 to 8.

```
b <- c(0.5, 0.75, 1, 2.5, 4, 6, 8, 10)  
a <- c(0.0499, 0.0491, 0.0507, 0.0505, 0.0513, 0.0493, 0.0507, 0.0500)  
library(lattice)  
xyplot(a ~1:8, type="l", col="blue", ylim=c(0,0.10))
```

Edit:
I mean that we have a plot of a line going through the coordinates (0.5,0.0409); (0.75,0.0491); (1, 0.0507) etc.

Comment: If you want to plot using both `a` and `b`, then `xyplot(a ~b, type="l", col="blue")` seems like the right starting point. What exactly do you want the limits of each axis to be? I'm still quite confused what the desired output is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to plot the components against each other, just

```
xyplot(a~b, type="l", col="blue", ylim=c(0,0.1))
```

[image]

Comment: I edit the question to be more clear. I know about the scales argument, but that does not help.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your question correctly, but if you are just trying to re-adjust the x axis to range from 0 to 10, simply add `xlim=c(0,10)`, so your last line would be `xyplot(a ~1:8, type="l", col="blue", ylim=c(0,0.10), xlim=c(0,10))`

Comment: Perhaps I'm not understanding the question correctly; however setting the xlim does seem to re-adjust the range of the x axis to go from 0 to 10 (a subtle change, as the original code went from 0 to 8). Just to test it, I set `xlim=c(0,100)` to see a much more drastic change of scale.